# laravel 10 inicia sesion pero no muestra los datos de sesion

Tags: php, laravel, session

Hola a todos eh estado practicando un poco de laravel haciendo un login basico. El caso es que al parecer hace login ya que despues de llenar el form de login me redirige a la pagina que especifique pero al momento de querer consultar los datos del usuario que inicio sesion me da errores del tipo NULL. Coloque una validacion de que si existe el login que no pueda ingresar a la vista del login pero tampoco funciona. Entonces en resumen laravel no captura la sesion.
Comparto el codigo por que eh intentado de todo y sigo con este problema

El login controller tengo

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\LoginRequest;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{


    public function index()
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return redirect('/admin/dashboard');
        }
        return view('login');
    }

    public function login(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->getCredentials();

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            return redirect()->intended('/admin/dashboard');
        }

        return redirect()->to('/login')->withErrors('usuario o pass incorrecto');
    }
}
```

En loginRequest

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Factory as ValidationFactory;

class LoginRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule|array|string>
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ];
    }

    public function getCredentials()
    {
        $username = $this->get('username');

        //validar si usuario es correo

        if ($this->isEmail($username)) {
            return [
                'email' => $username,
                'password' => $this->get('password')
            ];
        }
        return $this->only('username', 'password');
    }

    public function isEmail($value)
    {
        $factory = $this->container->make(ValidationFactory::class);
        //valida si lo ingresado es correo o no
        return !$factory->make(['username' => $value], ['username' => 'email'])->fails();
    }
}
```

en rutas

```
Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'index']);
Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'login']);
//dashboard
Route::get('/admin/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index']);
```

y el formulario login

```
  <form action="{{url('/login')}}" method="POST">
                                @csrf
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <label for="username" class="form-label">Usuario o correo</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter username">
                                </div>

                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <div class="float-end">
                                        <a href="auth-pass-reset-basic.html" class="text-muted">Forgot password?</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <label class="form-label" for="password-input">Contraseña</label>
                                    <div class="position-relative auth-pass-inputgroup mb-3">
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control pe-5 password-input"
                                            placeholder="Enter password" id="password-input" name="password">
                                        <button
                                            class="btn btn-link position-absolute end-0 top-0 text-decoration-none text-muted shadow-none password-addon"
                                            type="button" id="password-addon"><i
                                                class="ri-eye-fill align-middle"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="auth-remember-check">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="auth-remember-check">Remember me</label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="mt-4">
                                    <button class="btn btn-success w-100" type="submit">Iniciar Sesion</button>
                                </div>

                                <div class="mt-4 text-center">
                                    <div class="signin-other-title">
                                        <h5 class="fs-13 mb-4 title">Sign In with</h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-icon waves-effect waves-light"><i
                                                class="ri-facebook-fill fs-16"></i></button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-icon waves-effect waves-light"><i
                                                class="ri-google-fill fs-16"></i></button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-icon waves-effect waves-light"><i
                                                class="ri-github-fill fs-16"></i></button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-icon waves-effect waves-light"><i
                                                class="ri-twitter-fill fs-16"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

Comment: me pasa exactamente lo mismo, estoy usando laravel 10.10 y me encuentro con este problema, voy a probar con otras versiones y migrar mi proyecto de ser necesario, estoy usando Laravel + Inertia + React, al guarda datos bien, osea hace bien el registro pero con el login es que estoy teniendo problemas, asi como dices, hago un dd(auth()->user()) dentro del if y me imprime los datos del usuario, pero si en otra vista quiero ver esos datos con el midmo dd(), me imprime null

Comment: Inicia un nuevo proyecto laravel. En mo caso había un extraño bug por el que pasaba eso al no encontrar solución simplemente elimine ese proyecto e inicie uno nuevo y todo bien